# Can Pandoc use variables from Metadata.yaml in imported Markdown files?

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown, pandoc

I'm having a lot of trouble getting variables into my template. I have a LaTeX template, and I would like to use Markdown files for the content. The end result should be a PDF.

metadata.yaml:

```
---
varnameone:  'large heading'
varnametwo:  'baz'
varnamethree:
- threeone: textone
- threetwo: texttwo
---
```

template.tex:

```
\documentclass[12t, A4]{extarticle}
\usepackage{Styles.sty} 

\begin{document}

\import{chapters/}{chapter1.md} % MD-file probably not possible. So how?
\import{chapters/}{chapter2.md}
\import{chapters/}{chapter3.md}

\end{document}
```

chapter1.md:

```
# This is a $varnameone$

Lorem ipsum foo bar.

## Subheading
Lorem ipsum foo bar with a $varnametwo$ and more.

\if[varnametwo == 'baz']
Lorem ipsum foo bar with a $varnamethree.threetwo$ and more.
\endif 

Jade-style indentation would be even simpler:
if varnametwo == 'baz'
    Lorem ipsum foo bar with a $varnamethree.threetwo$ and more.
```

Here's the thing: I prefer to have Markdown files for the content, as they are the easiest to edit (by not so technical people that is). And I know that Pandoc understands them, but how do I get those variables in them?
Is this even possible?

I the end I would even like to have a server to batch-generate files with different Metadata files, or, if possible, with a JSON array instead of a yaml file. Does anyone know if that is possible too?

Comment: Use `--metadata-file=metadata.yaml` in your run command

Answer (score 4):

Pandoc variables can only be used in [pandoc templates](http://pandoc.org/README.html#templates), not the document itself. For that you should check out a [preprocessor like `gpp`](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-i-stopped-worring-and-started-using-markdown-like-tex/), a [pandoc filter like this one](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#replacing-placeholders-with-their-metadata-value) or other scripting/templating solutions.

Similarly, pandoc templates have a `$body$` variable where the document text is placed. You render a document with a template, not the other way around (as you tried with `\import{chapters/}{chapter1.md}` which is a LaTeX command and thus does not work to import markdown). But on Mac/Linux you can run: `pandoc -o foo.pdf chapter*.md` to concatenate all the markdown files before passing them to pandoc.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out. But in theory, could I use the current setup, writing the whole document in the template file (not using Markdown at all) ?

Comment: you mean: could you just use LaTeX instead? erm... sure...?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would like to know. Skipping the 'template' and writing the vars into the doc directly.